# Total from first row to this row -1 in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I want to sum everything from my first row, to the row just before the total.

I know the notation `=SUM(A1:A10)`

I want notation like this `=SUM(A1:A($THIS_ROW - 1))`

The purpose is so inserted rows between the items and total will be included without having to update the range every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(A1:A10)
```

If you insert a row between the items and the total (in A11), it will change to SUM(A1:A11) automatically.